# TikZ: black hole lensing effect

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, tikzlibrary

I am trying to draw a black hole in tikz, and then overlay it on a real astronomical image with stars in the background. So I take a real image and then plug in a black hole in between the stars, and the goal is that it ideally should look like in [this image here](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/f3e1864b0d0ed8a953d453ec300179d123826de0/0_80_4356_2613/master/4356.jpg?width=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=max&s=41b3df8cad4f598105ca5f91033da01c):

The difficult part is the lensing effect, so the aura of light around the black hole. I really don't know how to go about this to make it look realistic.

My first naive attempt is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  %generates a tightly fitting border around the work
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [orange,fill=white,very thin] (0,0) circle (.515);
\shade[ball color = black] (0,0) circle (.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When overlayed with a crop of [this astronomical image](https://www.eso.org/public/images/eso0949b/) (scroll down for download links in different qualities), this not yet really satisfying image:

[image]

> How can I improve this, in particular the light aura around the black hole?

It does not need to be photo-realistic. But an improvement from what I got so far would be great! Thanks a lot for help and suggestions!

Comment: For me it is a very nice question....+1. Excuse me: where you have put the image into the code? I have not seen this photo.

Comment: I suggest these effects: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTAwYwh8lP6PEuYCo_5r-jpPuR-g0cfTFI4tcA9iWFOczzsvyyX8cVzvCbyCklpIaKAr9M&usqp=CAU, https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/QvKyBb3LzY7gFPBxE8FFse.jpg, https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ79_laI0EDVblP8Xx2LsVghV_lDI0J9LgQi5tHMPITA3V8BxSbxHJaOwyj3WjUvf52YDE&usqp=CAU, https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRN7ILQ1hsgnDIZISCMU0g9LG7QfcoCH9lw3xKra4YY_4JYF76wNstN6g39W7_Hzp3DIg&usqp=CAU

Comment: Hi @Sebastiano . I did not overlay the black hole with the background in tikz. I only drew the blackhole in tikz, and then did the overlaying in Apple Keynote for the lack of a better software to do so. If I can do all of that in tikz, then that would be great! I am not sure how to do it. Do you know by chance?

Comment: Hi to you and welcome to the TeX.SE. In this site there are a lot of question as overlay a TikZ code on an image. In this moment I don't remember the links but you can definitely find it in my bookmarks. In my opinion it is a marginal aspect the biggest problem is how to create a nice and charming aura.

Comment: "I really don't know how to go about this to make it look realistic." What exactly does "realistic" mean here? We have relatively few actual pictures of black holes, and all I think are in false colors, with the glow coming from matter inflow (not gravitational lensing). :-)  If may help if you add a more precise description of what you think should be captured by a good illustration.

Comment: Hi @WillieWong ! Yes, you are right of course. Realistic is the wrong term. I linked an image in my question, which looks like what I would like to achieve about. So I would like to draw this lensing ring effects around it.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks, I will have a look! Yes, you are right, it is a secondary issue. ; )

Comment: @Britzel If you will not have an answer....you write me a comment that I put for you a bounty....My best regards.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I use a random generation of white dots and multiple passages (`\foreach` loops that make the code rather long) for the stars, and some circles with various transparencies for the black hole lens effect.  I don't know if this is close to what you were looking for.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\xdefinecolor{B}{RGB}{2, 17, 34}

\begin{document}

\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzset{
  star/.style={B, fill=white, path fading=fade out}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % background color
  \clip (-4, -4) rectangle (4, 4);
  \draw[white, shading=mradial, inner color=black,
  middle color=B!60!black, outer color=B]
  (-4, -4) rectangle (4, 4);

  % stars foreground
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 40}{%
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{\pgfmathresult}
    \filldraw[star] ({\a*360}: 1+\d/6) circle (.75pt);
  }
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 30}{%
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw[star] ({\a*360}: 1+1/6+\d) circle (\r pt);
  }
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 30}{%
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw[star] ({\a*360}: 2+1/6+\d) circle (1.5*\r pt);
  }
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 30}{%
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{random()}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw[star] ({\a*360}: 3+1/6+\d) circle (1.25*\r pt);
  }

  stars background
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 180}{%
    \pgfmathparse{rand}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{rand}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\pgfmathresult}
    \filldraw[white] (4*\x, 4*\y) circle (.3 pt);
  }

  % black hole
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \t using 1/\i] in {2, 3, ..., 20}{%
    \draw[white, thick, opacity=\t] (0, 0) circle (.9+\i/100);
  }
  \fill[black, opacity=.9] (0, 0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```